# I want to put dots if the text is long

Tags: html, css

Can someone help me with line clamp

After dots the text is continue

This is my HTML

```
 <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mt-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="/2020-02-24 15.18.25_1593079252.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="#"><h5 class="card-title">hrmndiiii</h5></a>
                    <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printe Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printe Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printe Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printe Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printe Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text o</p>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <small class="text-muted">Jun 25, 2020</small>
                    <small class="text-primary">
                                                #test 
                                        </small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is CSS
I'm using Bootstrap

```
.row .card-body{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

but  it doesn't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqnlF.png)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: You need to limit the height to only 3 lines (equal to line-camp) so reduce the height to consider the height of 3 lines

Comment: as you mentioned in your question's heading, that you want to apply 3 dots on the title, and as per your HTML, your title is, <h5 class="card-title">hrmndiiii</h5>, is this the thing you want to apply 3 dots on?

Comment: change height 200px to 76px;

Answer (score 0):

```
.card-body a, .card-body p.card-text  {
    width: 8.9em;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**for your width for adjust the width**

Answer (score 0):

Apply `height` and `overflow: hidden` property to the parent container.

Add `line-height` to the `card-body` e.g `line-height: 1.4em`

and then apply the height of `card` which will be `line-height*3` i.e `4.2em`

```css
.card {
   height: 4.2em; // line-height * 3
   overflow: hidden;
}

.card-body {
    line-height: 1.4em
     display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.a {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.b {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

div.c {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: "----"; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h1>The text-overflow Property</h1>

<p>The following two divs contains a text that will not fit in the box.</p>

<h2>text-overflow: clip (default):</h2>
<div class="a">Hello world!</div>

<h2>text-overflow: ellipsis:</h2>
<div class="b">Hello world!</div>

<h2>text-overflow: "----" (user defined string):</h2>
<div class="c">Hello world!</div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The text-overflow: "<em>string</em>" only works in 
Firefox.</p>

</body>
</html>
```